# Xcode: WebView & local HTML with images

Tags: html, xcode, image, uiwebview

I am trying to load an html file with a folder containing images, in a webView. I followed different tutorials without successfully loading the images. The latest tutorial i saw uses the code above:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"info1" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"mainInfo"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

However it gives me a SIGABRT if i use the **inDirectory**
Without it it runs but without loading the image. 
Can you pls help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure, but my guess is that you should do the following.  Don't use inDirectory, clearly your files are directly in the bundle.  (If when you copied the files in you did it by reference, then you would need it).

You should make sure that your html references the images as if they're in the same directory, so `<img src="img_name.jpg">.`  And NOT `<img src="folder/img_name.jpg">`

The next thing you should do is check to make sure the files are part of your bundle and not executable code.  So go to your "target -> build phases -> compile sources" and make sure any html or javascript files ARE NOT in there.  Then go down to "target -> build phases -> bundle resources" and make sure they ARE all in there.

Then run it again.  Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: "You should make sure that your html references the images as if they're in the same directory, so <img src="img_name.jpg">. And NOT <img src="folder/img_name.jpg">" THAT did it! Thank you very very much!